# Running into several "Expression must have pointer to class type" errors. C++, using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

first time poster here, and very novice c++ programmer (current 3rd semester working with the language) and I'm having some trouble. After googling around and searching the forum I've been unable to come up with a solution - any help you could offer would be great.

1st Header file:

**linked_list.h**

```
#ifndef  my_linked_list
#define my_linked_list

#include "Node.h"
#include <cstdlib>

namespace linked_list_version_0{

class linked_list {

public:

linked_list() {head = NULL; tail = NULL;}
~linked_list();

void insert_back (int x);
void insert_front (int x);
int remove_front ();
int remove_back();
bool empty() {return (head == NULL);}

private:

node * head;
node * tail;

}; //end class linked_list
}//end namespace linked_list_version_0

#endif
```

Implementation File:

**linked_list.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace node_version_0;
using namespace linked_list_version_0;

void linked_list::insert_front (int x) {

node *p = new node;
p->set_data (x);
p->set_next (head);
head = p;
if (head->next() == NULL) tail = head;  // takes care of inserting into the empty list
} //end insert_front

int linked_list::remove_front() {
// assumes the list is not empty

node *p = head;
int x =  p-> get_data(); //could not use data(), had to use get_data
head = head->next() ;
delete p;
if (head==NULL) tail = NULL;  // takes care of deleting only element in the list
return x;
}//end remove_front

linked_list::~linked_list() {

node * p;
while (head != NULL) {
   p=head;
head = head->next();
delete p;
}
tail = NULL;
}//deconstructor

void linked_list::insert_back (int x) {
node * q = new node;
q->set_data(x);
q->set_next(NULL);
if (tail == NULL) head = q; else tail -> set_next(q);
tail = q;
} //end insert_back

int linked_list::remove_back () {
// assumes the list isn’t empty

node *q = tail;
int x= tail->data();
if (head == tail)
{head = NULL; tail = NULL;}
else {
tail = head;
while (tail->next()!=q)
 tail = tail->next();
}
delete q;
tail->set_next(NULL);
return x;
} //end remove back
```

2nd Header File

**Node.h**

```
#ifndef my_node
#define my_node

#include "linked_list.h"

//implementation file unnecessary for this header as
//inline declarations are used

namespace node_version_0{

class node{

public:

node();
void set_data(int x) {data = x;} //sets the data value of the node
void set_next( node * n) { next = n;} //sets the address to the next node
int get_data() const {return data;} //returns the data value from the node to user
node * next() {return next;}; //returns the address of the next node 
const node * next() const {return next;} //same as above, "write protected"

private:

int data;
node * next;

};//end class node
}//end namespace node_version_0

#endif
```

So the problem I'm running into is with the **linked_list.cpp** implementation file.

All the occurrences of *head->next()* are giving the error "Expression must have pointer to class type". The same error is occurring for all occurrences of *tail-> whatevers here*

So I'm sure is something simple - but being pretty novice I just can't figure it out. I know this code probably looks sloppy to you guys haha, so any pointers you have would be much appreciated. FYI, this is a school assignment.

Sorry if any of the formatting is off/hard to read. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected it to fail earlier than that, to be honest.  Due to the order of your include files, when the compiler reaches the declaration of your `linked_list` class, it wont know what `node` is.  Which is why I would expect the first error to be in linked_list.h.

From what I can see, `Node.h` doesn't need to include 'linked_list.h`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed the 'linked_list.h' from Node.h - at that point I had run out of ways to google the problem and just gave that a shot. Now, I tried switching the order of the #include files in 'linked_list.cpp', but I'm still running into the same error, any thoughts? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You could try being explicit with the namespace that node is in in linked_list.h.  Or hack it and add `using namespace node_version_0;` in the top of linked_list.h.